# Subdivision + Solidify + Bridge Edge Loop

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I try to create a chair following the youtube tutorial. Could you guys tell me why the object seems like broken, not a smooth rectangle after I use solidify. Also, the same happen again when I use the modifier in order Solidify > Subdivision and then Bridge Edge Loop to connect two faces. Below images show the problems and the file link is also added [Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vsNByXCwX-4aFY4Zinw5S9P2Ww8iq-a9/view?usp=sharing). Appreciated if you can help me out of this trouble.

[image: status without modifier][image: With Solidify][image: Solidify + Subdivision + Bridge Edge Loop]

Answer (score 1):

Your face orientation is causing this problem. To see face orientation you can check Face Orientation under Viewport Overlays tab. Blue is outside. Red is inside.

[image: Face Orientation]

To solve this select your object and toggle to edit mode. Press <kbd>a</kbd> to select all. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to Recalculate Outside. This fill flip normals that are inside-out. You can also select Mesh tab and from Normals select Recalculate Outside.

[image: Recalculate Normals]